# Calculating number of chips and determining chip denominations for players

Tags: javascript, optimization, performance, beginner

I have a large JavaScript function to calculate the number of chips, and which denomination of chips to show as the players chip stack. It's done on the base of 10.

I have chip denominations worth 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000. For a total of 7 different chip values, and 7 for loops in my JavaScript code.

Here's an example of how the 100,000 chips look when there is 5 in that spot:

[image: 100000 chips]

Any John Nash's in here want to help me get this down to like one or two `for` loops?  Any other improvements you'd like to mention?

Also, I use `$('.chips').remove();` right before the next hand, so that all the chips are removed and then recalculated again by a call to `chipStack();`. So that way it doesn't just add to the existing chips and show an incorrect stack of chips. But also means that every hand the below JavaScript is getting ran.

**JavaScript:**

```
function chipStack() {
    var a = hand1.cChips.toString();      //this gets the current chip amount in a string
    var c = parseInt(a.substr(-1));       //this is the first 0-9
    var d = parseInt(a.substr(-2, 1));    //second 0-9, in the tenth's spot
    var e = parseInt(a.substr(-3, 1));    // etc etc etc
    var f = parseInt(a.substr(-4, 1));              
    var g = parseInt(a.substr(-5, 1));
    var h = parseInt(a.substr(-6, 1));
    var j = parseInt(a.substr(-7, 1));   // this is the millionth spot
        if (c > 0) {   // if the last number is 0, doesn't run, so doesn't show any chips
            eett = 4; // this is for css style bottom: number, for stack like appearance
            for (var x = 0; x < c; x++) {
                $('.chip1c').prepend('<div class="chip1 chips" style="bottom: -' + eett + 'px;"></div>');
                eett += 4;
            }
        }
        if (d > 0) {
            eett = 4;
            for (var x = 0; x < d; x++) {
                $('.chip10c').prepend('<div class="chip10 chips" style="bottom: -' + eett + 'px;"></div>');
                eett += 4;
            }
        }
        if (e > 0) {
            eett = 4;
            for (var x = 0; x < e; x++) {
                $('.chip100c').prepend('<div class="chip100 chips" style="bottom: -' + eett + 'px;"></div>');
                eett += 4;
            }
        }
        if (f > 0) {
            eett = 4;
            for (var x = 0; x < f; x++) {
                $('.chip1kc').prepend('<div class="chip1000 chips" style="bottom: -' + eett + 'px;"></div>');
                eett += 4;
            }
        }
        if (g > 0) {
            eett = 4;
            for (var x = 0; x < g; x++) {
                $('.chip10kc').prepend('<div class="chip10000 chips" style="bottom: -' + eett + 'px;"></div>');
                eett += 4;
            }
        }
        if (h > 0) {
            eett = 4;
            for (var x = 0; x < h; x++) {
                $('.chip100kc').prepend('<div class="chip100000 chips" style="bottom: -' + eett + 'px;"></div>');
                eett += 4;
            }
        }
        if (j > 0) {
            eett = 4;
            for (var x = 0; x < j; x++) {
                $('.chip1mc').prepend('<div class="chip1000000 chips" style="bottom: -' + eett + 'px;"></div>');
                eett += 4;
            }
        }
}
```

**CSS:**

```
.chips { width: 40px; height: 40px; border-radius: 100px; position: absolute; }

.ccont { position: absolute; width: 40px; height: 40px; }
.chip1c { right: 0; bottom: -30px; }
.chip10c { right: 50px; bottom: -35px; }
.chip100c { right: 100px; bottom: -40px; }
.chip1kc { right: 150px; bottom: -40px; }
.chip10kc { right: 200px; bottom: -38px; }
.chip100kc { right: 250px; bottom: -35px; }
.chip1mc { right: 300px; bottom: -30px; }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="chip1mc ccont"></div>
<div class="chip100kc ccont"></div>
<div class="chip10kc ccont"></div>
<div class="chip1kc ccont"></div>
<div class="chip100c ccont"></div>
<div class="chip10c ccont"></div>
<div class="chip1c ccont"></div>
```

Comment: **7 for loops, 9 variables, 7 if statements, and one function** - doesn't it sound like you need more functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the cases should be handled generically; the variables should be in an array.  The class names, such as `chip10kc`, should be renamed to `chip10000c`.

I would also split the calculation from the presentation.

```
/**
 * Decomposes a value as a sum of differently denominated chips.
 * The value must be a nonnegative integer.
 * Returns a seven-element array with the number of one-chips, ten-chips, …
 * million-chips.  (Some of those elements may have undefined values.)
 */
function chipCounts(value) {
    var chips = ('' + value).split('').reverse().map(function (e) { return parseInt(e) });

    // Handle value < 1 million or value >= 10 million
    chips.length = 7;
    chips[6] = Math.floor(value / 1000000);

    return chips;
}

function chipStack(chipCounts) {
    for (var exp = 0, denom = 1; exp < chipCounts.length; exp++, denom *= 10) {
        var $div = $('.chip' + denom + 'c');
        for (var c = 0, eett = 4; c < chipCounts[exp]; c++, eett += 4) {
            $div.prepend('<div class="chip' + denom + ' chips" style="bottom: -' + eett + 'px;"></div>');
        }
    }
}

// Test case
chipStack(chipCounts(31415));
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use the mod operator (`%`)?  Something along this line (I don't really know JavaScript; below is just the concept):

```
value = parsetInt( chips.toString() );
base = 0.1;

while( value > 0 ){
    stack = value % 10;
    value = Math.floor( value / 10 );
    base *= 10

    eett = 4
    for( var x = 0; x < stack; x++){
        // add stack with class = "chip"+unit+" chips"
        eett += 4;
    }
}
```